# Why does my Qcache_hits = Qcache_inserts

Tags: mysql

Why does my Qcache_hits = Qcache_inserts?  I know we are running similar queries so the hits should be greater than the inserts.  The first 4 million queries showed up in both qcache_hits and Qchache_inserts and were equal to each other until the cache was full.  Once the cache was full, Qcache inserts + qcache pruners equaled qcache hits.